# DataProcPySparkOperator cluster region and zone issue

Tags: pyspark, airflow

Issue on using DataProcPySparkOperator . Below is the task I added in my DAG :

```
run_pyspark_job= DataProcPySparkOperator(
    task_id='pyspark_operator_test',
    main='/root/airflow/dags/basic_eda.py',
    job_name='test_pyspark_job',
    cluster_name='test-cluster-20180502',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    region='global',
    zone='us-central1-b'
)
```

Getting below error :

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_id/regions/global/jobs:submit?alt=json returned "Not found: Cluster projects/project_id/regions/global/clusters/cluster-1"

Its not pointing to correct cluster

Please suggest what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters were changed in Airflow 1.9. To specify Cluster id, `dataproc_cluster` parameter was used which changed to `cluster_name` in 1.9.

So if you are using apache-airflow<='1.8.2', then use `dataproc_cluster` to specify the cluster_id (`'test-cluster-20180502'`).

Check: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#deprecated-features